# adding same index values of two list in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

```
A = [[0,1,3,2,200,250],
     [1,2,5,3,600,850],
     [1,3,1,1,100,100],
     [3,4,4,2,650,900],
     [2,4,3,2,450,500],
     [4,5,3,2,500,620],
     [5,6,2,1,500,600],
     [4,6,4,2,600,900],
     [2,3,0,0,0,0]]

B = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Is there a way in which I could add the values of B as the last index number of each list in A? So that A becomes this:

```
A = [[0,1,3,2,200,250,4],
     [1,2,5,3,600,850,5],
     [1,3,1,1,100,100,6],
     [3,4,4,2,650,900,7],
     [2,4,3,2,450,500,8],
     [4,5,3,2,500,620,9],
     [5,6,2,1,500,600,10],
     [4,6,4,2,600,900,11],
     [2,3,0,0,0,0,12]]
```

If i try the following I get to many combinations:

```
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        i.append(j)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight forward list comprehension makes a new list:

```
In [123]: C = [a+[b] for a,b in zip(A,B)]
In [124]: C
Out[124]: 
[[0, 1, 3, 2, 200, 250, 4],
 [1, 2, 5, 3, 600, 850, 5],
 [1, 3, 1, 1, 100, 100, 6],
 [3, 4, 4, 2, 650, 900, 7],
 [2, 4, 3, 2, 450, 500, 8],
 [4, 5, 3, 2, 500, 620, 9],
 [5, 6, 2, 1, 500, 600, 10],
 [4, 6, 4, 2, 600, 900, 11],
 [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12]]
```

`+` is concatenate for lists; the only trick is to turn the numeric `b` value into a list first.

Or to modify `A` itself:

```
In [125]: for a, b in zip(A,B): a.append(b)
```

`zip` makes it easy to iterate through `A` and `B` together.  Iteration with a `for i in range(len(A))` also works.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
In [60]: import numpy as np

In [65]: res = np.column_stack([A,B]).tolist()

In [66]: res
Out[66]: 
[[0, 1, 3, 2, 200, 250, 4],
 [1, 2, 5, 3, 600, 850, 5],
 [1, 3, 1, 1, 100, 100, 6],
 [3, 4, 4, 2, 650, 900, 7],
 [2, 4, 3, 2, 450, 500, 8],
 [4, 5, 3, 2, 500, 620, 9],
 [5, 6, 2, 1, 500, 600, 10],
 [4, 6, 4, 2, 600, 900, 11],
 [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12]]
```

**OR:**

Use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) library:

```
In [53]: import pandas as pd

In [54]: res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(A), pd.DataFrame(B)], 1).values.tolist()

In [55]: res
Out[55]: 
[[0, 1, 3, 2, 200, 250, 4],
 [1, 2, 5, 3, 600, 850, 5],
 [1, 3, 1, 1, 100, 100, 6],
 [3, 4, 4, 2, 650, 900, 7],
 [2, 4, 3, 2, 450, 500, 8],
 [4, 5, 3, 2, 500, 620, 9],
 [5, 6, 2, 1, 500, 600, 10],
 [4, 6, 4, 2, 600, 900, 11],
 [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i].append(B[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [`numpy` has been tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) in the question, a straightforward concatenation using [`numpy.concatenate()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) along `axis=1` would yield the required result.

```
# convert `A` and `B` to numpy arrays in advance and then do:
In [17]: np.concatenate((A, B[:, None]), axis=1)
Out[17]: 
array([[  0,   1,   3,   2, 200, 250,   4],
       [  1,   2,   5,   3, 600, 850,   5],
       [  1,   3,   1,   1, 100, 100,   6],
       [  3,   4,   4,   2, 650, 900,   7],
       [  2,   4,   3,   2, 450, 500,   8],
       [  4,   5,   3,   2, 500, 620,   9],
       [  5,   6,   2,   1, 500, 600,  10],
       [  4,   6,   4,   2, 600, 900,  11],
       [  2,   3,   0,   0,   0,   0,  12]])
```